# How to call simulink model(.slx) from script

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm a super beginner in Simulink models and control systems.
I have .slx Simulink model for drone dynamics system. 
It takes in two inputs (roll cmd, pitch cmd) and outputs velocity x, velocity y, position x, and position y.

From here, it seems like I can open the system by calling

```
open_system('myModel.slx', 'loadable');
```

[image: simulink model]

But how do I put inputs and get output values? 
Is there a way I can do this in a gui?

EDIT:
Here is the full layout of my model:[image]

When I did

```
roll_CMD=10;
pitch_CMD=20;
```

I got a warning saying:

```
Input port 1 of 'SimpleDroneDynamics/...' is not connected.
```

1. How do I feed inputs using port numbers?
2. How do I get outputs with port numbers? I tried

   [vx, vy, px, py] = sim('SimpleDroneDynamics.slx');

and got an error saying

```
Number of left-hand side argument doesn't match block diagram...
```

3. Is there a way to continuously feed inputs at every time step? This being controller module, I think I'm supposed to feed in different values based on output position and velocity.

EDIT2: 
I'm using Matlab2017a

Comment: Start by reading [Getting Started With Simulink](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/getting-started-with-simulink.html) to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all Simulink model use main Matlab workspace. So you can change your variables values at command window (or just at your script) and run Simulink model.
   [image]
2. There are several ways to initialize this constants for Simulink. One more useful way is to create script containing all your variables and load it at Simulink model starts. You can do it by adding script name in Simulink/Model Explorer/Callbacks. (There are different callbacks - on Loading, on Starting and etc.). Read more about this: [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2008/12/25/initializing-parameters/).
3. Now you can run your simulation using `sim` function:

   ```
   sim('name_of_model')
   ```

   `name_of_model` must contain path if model is not in the active MATLAB folder (active folder you can see in your matlab window just under the main menu).

   There are different properties of `sim` function, read about them in help this can be useful for you. By the way: you can change some parameters of your model using `sim`. You even can find any block in your model and change it's properties. Read more [about `sim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html) and about [finding current blocks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98069-how-can-i-change-the-value-of-a-constant-block-programmatically-during-a-simulation). Interesting that the last solution give you ability to change parameters during the simulation!
4. About getting output. After you run simulation you get `tout` variable in main workspace. It is an array of timesteps. But if you add [outport block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/outport.html) (like at my image) you also get another variable in workspace `yout`. `yout` is an Datasets. It contain all your outports values. For 2 outports for example:

   ```
   yout

   yout = 

     Simulink.SimulationData.Dataset
     Package: Simulink.SimulationData

     Characteristics:
             Name: 'yout'
       Total Elements: 2

     Elements:
       1 : ''
       2 : ''
   ```

   Get the values of any of outports:

   ```
   yout.get(1).Values
   ```

   it is a timeseries data type, so:

   `yout.get(1).Values.Time` - give you times

   `yout.get(2).Values.Data` - give you values of this outport at each time
5. We have one more method to take output values:

   ```
   [t,x,y] = sim('model_name')
   ```

   it returns double arrays. `t`- time array, `y` - matrix of all outports values (it already double and contain only values without times, but for each simulation time!)
6. So now you can create common Matlab GUI and work at this variables! There is no any difficulties. You can read more about GUI for Simulink [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/06/01/use-matlab-guis-with-simulink-models/).

Comment: I didn't get yout, just tout? is it because the input ports weren't connected like the warnings said?

Comment: I see you already added outports. Use `[t,x,y] = sim(..)` then. Try it!

Comment: I don't understand. [t, x, y] = sim(...) worked but I have 4 output ports. So I tried [t, vx, vy, px, py]  = sim(...) but that didn't work... How do I get all 4 outputs separately? And how do I feed inputs into sim?

Comment: @MoneyBall NoNo! Use exactly `[t,x,y] = sim(...)`. And third variable `y` will contain 4 columns - it is all your outports! So use `y(:,1), y(:,2)` and etc to get them one by one.

Comment: I get `y` with 6 columns... And I get multiple warnings saying input and output ports are not connected. Am I supposed to add constant blocks?

Comment: @MoneyBall Maybe first two columns are your input data? Roll Cmd and Pitch Cmd. Can you check it's values? Another 4 are your outputs.

Comment: Well, both inputs and outputs are all `0`s because I never feed any inputs in. I can verify that `t` is timestep since it increments by `0.2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146075/discussion-between-mikhail-sam-and-moneyball).

Comment: @MoneyBall, Hi Benjamin! Serial voting was reverse, and I lost 175 Rep :D can you accept this answer again? :)

Comment: I just did. What happened? Is it because of me they reversed it?

Comment: @MoneyBall looks like SO has some protection against serial voting :)

Answer (score 3):

About the first two points of your question:

**In simulink:**

[image: simulink block diagram]

- For the inputs you can use a constant block and when you double click the input block you can assign a value, which can be a workspace variable.

[image: constant block]

1. To get the outputs to your workspace you can use the simout block (make sure to put Save format to array).
2. Connect inputs to your simulink model
3. Connect outputs of your simulink model to the simout blocks.

**MATLAB script**

```
   clc;
   clear all;

   roll = 10;
   pitch = 20;

   sim('/path_to_simulinkmodel.slx')

   time = simout(:,1);
   velocity_X = simout(:,2);
   velocity_Y = simout(:,3);
   position_X = simout(:,4);
   position_Y = simout(:,5);
```

**About the third point of your question**

You can define the duration of your simulation in the block diagram editor. You can put a variable which is defined in the calling script. There are multiple ways of achieving time dependent input variables:

- One option I personally don't recommend is using a for-loop and calling the simulink model with a different value of *roll* and *pitch*

  ```
   for i = 1:numberOfTimesteps
      roll = ...
      ...
      sim('simulinkModel.slx')
   end
  ```
- A second and more efficient approach is changing the constant blocks to other source blocks like ramp signals or sinusoid signals

Comment: I tried your method but it seems like the names of the variables I have are different. Is there a way to connect my inputs to ports directly?

Comment: I put some more information + images in the text, I'm just starting and due to my limited reputation I can only upload two images, sorry about that

Comment: I'm so sorry but how do I add constant block in the gui? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Either you click on the block diagram and start typing constant or you go to the library browser icon in the toolbar and go to sources => constant